# Samsung CLX 3180 doesn't print colors

Tags: linux, printer, samsung

I recently got my hands on an old Samsung CLX 3180 laser printer. It seems to work quite well with the "Generic PCL Laser Printer" driver. Unfortunately, though, it doesn't print in color.

I've tried to use the "system-config-printer" tool but there I only see the advanced option "print-color-mode: monochrome" as depicted below: [image]

There is no color option. Using the official [ULD HP drivers](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/samsung-clx-3180-color-laser-multifunction-printer-series/19134246) or [general HP drivers](https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/) doesn't help either. These drivers don't result in a working configuration and I can't even print a test page using those.

Any help or ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Option one is to use the software provided by HP which now maintains printer drivers for the device:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/samsung-clx-3180-color-laser-multifunction-printer-series/19134246

Option two is "Generic Color PCL Printer" You could also try the various versions later of PCL, likely PCL4, PCL5, PCL6 and PCL XL drivers.

You probably could also modify the driver for the 3185 printer, or even use it out of box. The only difference between that printer and yours is the 3185 has an integrated network server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but unfortunately both options don't work for me as described in the OP. I don't have the "Generic Color PCL Printer" option, as I can only see "Generic PCL Printer" in the corresponding drop-down menu.